# How to bind winsock port's of server and multiple clients c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a server program lets say it listens on port 8888. Suppose I connect to server from multiple clients and maintain threads for each client. Now when a new client is added by thread_join in server. The server interacts with the latest one and when this thread is closed I get connection reset error(10054) while sending message to the previous client. So I wanted to bind a port for client and whenever a thread is created I want to store the particular port number and respond to the client so that there will be no connection reset problems on winsock. Can any one suggest me the model of client code or else is there a way to tackle this?
**// I am considering localhost so that Ip addresses don't change
// connection reset error I get is 10054 (WSAGetLastError()) by winsock**

//server Code

```
#undef UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
using namespace std;
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
void *connection_handler(void *);
static SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
int iSendResult;
int iResult;

// class Authenticate {
//     bool getAuthenticated() {

//     }
// };





int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int *new_sock;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    pthread_t sniffer_thread[5];
    int i = 0;

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //freeaddrinfo(result);

        printf("starting\n");
        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, 5);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        // Accept a client socket
    while( i < 5) {
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&hints, (socklen_t*)&c);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Connection accepted\n");

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread[i] , NULL ,  connection_handler , NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }
        //cout << sniffer_thread[i].get_id();
         i++;
        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
    }
        printf("Handler assigned\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
             pthread_join(sniffer_thread[i] , NULL);
        }


    if (ClientSocket < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    char recvbuf[2000];

     do {
        cout << GetCurrentThreadId()<<endl;
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, 2000, 0);
        printf("%s%d\n",recvbuf,strlen(recvbuf) );
            if(strcmp(recvbuf,"quit") == 0)
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
        recvbuf[iResult] = '\0';
        //fflush(stdout);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Client Says: \t%s\n", recvbuf);
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(recvbuf,100,stdin);
            int ln = strlen(recvbuf)-1;
            if(recvbuf[ln] == '\n')
                recvbuf[ln] = '\0';

            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, strlen(recvbuf), 0 );
            fflush(stdout);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
            }
            printf("Bytes sent from server: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

        }

    } while (iResult > 0);
//Free the socket pointer
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a separate thread is created for each connected client, why the server communicates only with the last client? The communication should be performed in parallel, right? Do you have a code to show?
Another topic is why one thread per client is not good approach, a thread pool should be used instead.

Comment: I have update my server code.

Comment: `iResult` and `iSendResult` are global variables but used by several threads. The variables are used in the local context, so I would rather move them to the scopes they belong, rather then synchronizing them.

Comment: ok @karastojko I have made the change, but still I have a problem.
In my case I am taking input from client sending it to server and vice versa. Connection reset problem has gone but winsock error 10053 is coming. [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx). Help me in solving this too. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I believe you have the similar case with `ClientSocket`. it is the same variable used by all threads, thus used by all connected clients - sound like a trouble. I believe you should make the variable local and transfer it to `connection_handler()`. This way, one thread uses its own client socket for the communication.

Comment: Thanks for the info Karastojko. Got it.